# How to copy S3 object from one region to another when vpc endpoint is enabled

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Recently I was unable to copy files using the `s3.copyObject(sourceBucket, sourceKey, destBucket, destKey);` because of 2 reasons.

1) The source and destination buckets are in 2 different regions (us-east-1 and us-east2 in my case).

2) The region where the server resides is in a VPC which has an S3 endpoint enabled.   S3 endpoint is an internal connection to S3, *but only in the same region*

Given that we are moving large files, we could not download and then upload even temporarily.  We also wanted to keep the S3 endpoint in place, because the application makes serious use of S3 assets once in region.

Comment: What is the error?  Which region is source, and which is destination, and which region is your code in?  An S3 endpoint only gives you direct access to buckets in your own region -- other regions require Internet access.  It sounds like nothing to do with the endpoint itself, but rather a lack of connectivity to the remote region.  You should not need to resort to the workaround, below.

Comment: I agree I SHOULDN'T need it, but there seems to be a bug in the AWS Java SDK.
Error was along the lines that only region us-east-2 could be accessed through the VPC endpoint and that the source bucket is in us-east-1. 
The code was running in us-east-2 in a VPC with S3 Endpoint enabled.
I identified it as the culprit, as I could copy files as soon as the S3 Endpoint was removed from routing table for the subnet.
This is not an issue with GetObject command, as you can specify the region on the client.   There is no way to specify the source and destination regions on the client for copy.

Comment: Specifying us-east-1 in the S3 client constructor should accomplish the purpose.  I'll have to do some digging at the wire level because removing the S3 endpoint shouldn't have made any difference, but I am starting to suspect that perhaps there's something quirky about endpoints that I need to understand better.  Without an S3 endpoint, if you ask one region to identify the location of a bucket in another region, it will do it for you.  I wonder if the endpoint somehow breaks this behavior, throwing an exception that the SDK doesn't anticipate.

Comment: I think it has to do with the copy command using the generic s3 endpoints rather than the region specific ones.  The VPC endpoint redirects all traffic going to the generic S3 endpoint (dns).  SO unless you explicitly specify which S3 endpoint to hit, the endpoint will block the request as it goes to a different region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to stream copy the files from one stream to another.  I wrote this simple function which will handle it.

ZipException is just a custom exception.  Throw whatever you want.

Hopefully this helps somebody.

```
public static void copyObject(AmazonS3 sourceClient, AmazonS3 destClient, String sourceBucket, String sourceKey, String destBucket, String destKey) throws IOException {

    S3ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
    try {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(sourceBucket, sourceKey);
        S3Object object = sourceClient.getObject(request);

        inStream = object.getObjectContent();
        destClient.putObject(destBucket,
                destKey, inStream, object.getObjectMetadata());


    } catch (SdkClientException e) {
        throw new ZipException("Unable to copy file.", e);
    } finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            inStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```